# Multi levels Google Analytics regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to crack a regex to select deeper levels in the URL path (after several /'s)

The following list is URL's I'd like to match:

MATCH THIS

```
/lokalforeningar/syd/skane-lan/malmo/
/lokalforeningar/syd/skane-lan/eslov/
/lokalforeningar/syd/jonkopings-lan/jonkoping-huskvarna/
```

The following list is URL's I'd like to NOT match:

DONT MATCH THIS

```
/lokalforeningar/?county=Sk%C3%A5ne+l%C3%A4n#counties
/lokalforeningar/syd/skane-lan/svedala/kalender/
/lokalforeningar/syd/skane-lan/eslov/kontakta-oss-/ 
/lokalforeningar/syd/skane-lan/lund/verksamheter/lokalforeningens-projekt/ellen-allan/
/om-oss/
/press/
/stod-oss/manadsgivare/
```

In other words, the regex I'm trying to crack is:

1. First match /lokalforeningar
2. Then match /syd
3. Then match "some symbol (letters, numbers or just symbols)" in the third level /
4. Then match "another symbol (letters, numbers or just symbols)" in the third level".

$

And then no more after that.

How would I do this the best way? Or any way at all?

/Seif

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to add it but forgot...

The following is the regex I tried but failed. Seems the answer has come below. I'll try that one!

^\/lokalforeningar\/syd\/.*\/.*$

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex :

```
^\/lokalforeningar\/syd\/.*?\/.*?\/$
```

try this demo http://regexr.com/3d14m